# SQL substract one columns two rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one table

```
 date
 7.1.2019 8:15:35
 7.1.2019 8:15:38
 7.1.2019 9:23:23
 7.1.2019 9:23:43
 7.1.2019 9:24:02
```

and I need this table

```
 0:00:00
 0:00:03
 1:07:45
 0:00:20
 0:00:19
```

and how i can change format : number to hh:mi:ss ?

Comment: what's the data type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `LAG` window function with Calculation.

```
SELECT  coalesce(to_char(Dt,'hh:mi:ss'),'0:00:00')
FROM (
 SELECT  "date" - LAG("date") OVER(ORDER BY "date") Dt
 FROM T1
) t;
```

Comment: i have sql developer